# Angular 4 Image Upload

Tags: angular, image-uploading, angular4-forms, angular4-httpclient

I want to upload image through HTTP post API. My input is like this.

```
<input type="file" (change)="changedata($event)" name="file"/>
```

And Changedata() function .

```
let fileList: FileList = event.target.files;  
    if (fileList.length > 0) {
      let file: File = fileList[0]; 
      let formData: FormData = new FormData();  
          formData.append('File', file, file.name);  
            this.mainservice.updateIcon(formData).subscribe(responseData=>{
            console.log(' Reposnce Data ',responseData)                
   })
}
```

When I check Request Payload its not send image .. see  https://www.screencast.com/t/vKFKj0S3
How I can send image in base64 ?

Answer (score 0):

```
<input id="profile" type="file" name="profile" required (change)="uploadImage()">
```

and Uploadimage Function

```
    public uploadImage(): void {
    let files = this.element.nativeElement.querySelector('#profile').files;
    let formData = new FormData();
    let file = files[0];
    formData.append( 'userID', this.userID); // if you want pass other value 
    formData.append('profile', file, file.name); // add image  in FormData
    // pass image to service
     this.fileUpload.uploadFile(formData).subscribe( res => res);
}
```

in uploadFile ->>Service

```
    public uploadFile(formdata: any ) {

      return this.http.post('ApiURL here', formdata).catch(this.errorHandler);
      // return this.apiUrl;
    }

private errorHandler(error: Response) {
      console.error('Error Occured: ' + error);
      return Observable.throw(error || 'Some Error on Server Occured');
    }
```